# Replace hyperlink with text from linked document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a three worddokuments. The first hast the following structure:

```
Text
Hyperlink
Text
Hyperlink
```

I try to accomplish the following marcro: Open document 1, loop throu the hyperlinks. Open the hyperlinked documents and insert the text in the documents where the hyperlink in document 1 is.

What I accomplished yet is

```
Dim hLink As Hyperlink
Dim doc As Document
'Loop throu all hyperlinks
    For Each hLink In ThisDocument.Hyperlinks
        'Set objectref to document behind hyperlink
        Set doc = Documents.Open(hLink.Address)
        'AAAAnd Close it.
        doc.Close
    Next
```

My problem is, that I do not know how to put the text of the open document, where the hyperlink is and delete this hyperlink. For further puproses the document 1 has to be flexible so that the user can insert hyperlinks and the functionality of inserting is still working.

I thought of deleting the hyperlink and place a bookmark at the same position, name the bookmark, insert the text and delete the bookmark afterwards, but I do not get the hyperlink replaced by a bookmark. I found the hyperlink.Range.Bookmarks Property but no way to use it for my purposes. Anyone who can help me get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim i As Long

For i = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
  Dim link As Hyperlink, r As Range, addr As String

  Set link = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks(i)
  Set r = link.Range
  addr = link.Address

  link.Delete
  r.InsertFile addr
Next
```